# Prove the length of a linear combination of an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_p\}$ where $B$ is an orthonormal basis for a subspace $W$.  Let $v$ be any vector in $W$, where $v=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_pu_p$. prove that $$||v||^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_p^2$$

So obviously, since the length of every vector $u$ is 1, this makes intuitive sense, but I cannot figure out how to write this, I was thinking about writing it all out like this

$$||v||^2=(a_1u_{11}+a_2u_{21}+...+a_pu_{p1})^2 + (a_1u_{12}+a_2u_{22}+...+a_pu_{p2})^2 + ... +(a_1u_{1n}+a_2u_{2n}+...+a_pu_{pn})^2$$

and then trying to get all of the $u's$ by themselves but that gets extremely messy and does not seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to expand
$$
\|v\|^2 = \langle a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_pu_p, \;a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_pu_p \rangle
$$
by bilinearity an note that $\langle u_i,u_j \rangle = 0 $ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$

Comment: We have not learned bilinearity yet, so I don't think I completely understand your notation

Comment: @Sam It's a property of the inner product:
$$\langle \alpha a+ \beta b, c \rangle = \alpha \langle a,c\rangle + \beta \langle b,c \rangle$$
For all vectors $a,b,c$ and scalars $\alpha,\beta$. Together with symmetry ($\langle a,b\rangle = \langle b,a\rangle$) you get the bilinearity wich is used here.

Comment: Is there another way to solve this problem?  Since we have not learned it I can't imagine I am expected to prove it this way.

Comment: Try the case $p=2$